# В чем разница смысла описаний "Процент полученных показов" и "ППП" в гугл рекламе?

Tags: ads

1. Процент полученных показов на верхней позиции в поисковой сети – это отношение количества произошедших показов на верхней позиции страницы результатов поиска к расчетному числу показов, которые могли состояться на этой позиции. Используйте этот показатель для назначения ставок за показ в верхней части страницы результатов поиска.
   Верхняя позиция объявления означает любую позицию выше обычных результатов поиска. Возможность показа зависит от ставок, настроек таргетинга, статуса рассмотрения и качества объявлений.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Процент полученных показов на верхней позиции в поисковой сети – это доля показов товарных объявлений на наиболее заметном месте на странице.
   Процент полученных показов на верхней позиции = количество показов на самой верхней позиции / количество доступных показов на верхней позиции.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем разница? я не могу понять, смысл один и тот же, написано то же самое только другими словами? гугл издевается?